# Помогите пофиксить выполнение скрипта много раз ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, get

Вот код ниже, и при клике на FIRST он выводит в item `FIRST` и в консоль `AAAAAA`, но если нажать FIRST, а потом MAIN и снова FIRST, то выведет уже 2 `АААААА` в консоль, если нажать еще раз на MAIN, то 3 и тд, как это зафиксить, мне надо чтобы `ААААА` выводилось 1 раз всегда.

```js
$('.nth').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  history.pushState(null, null, this.getAttribute('data-page'));
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'http://slides/' + this.getAttribute('data-page'),
    data: {
      ajax: 'ajaxtrue'
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('.item').html(data);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.item {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
}

.nth {
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 58px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div class="nth" data-page="/">MAIN</div>
  <div class="nth" data-page="/pag/first">FIRST</div>
  <div class="nth" data-page="/pag/sec">SECOND</div>
  <div class="nth" data-page="/pag/three">THIRD</div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Это first.php:

```html
<div>FIRST</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  console.log('AAAAAAAAAAAA');
</script>
```

Comment: Нипанятна)) А для чего это придумано? Давайте разберемся с целью всего этого движения, так вот, зачем это?

Comment: Для того, чтобы подгружать контент по ajax

Comment: какой контент должен подгружаться при щелчке по MAIN?

Comment: Проблема роутинга на php. `pag/first` и `/` отдают один и тот же контент.

Comment: @KostiantynOkhotnyk это объясняет описываемое поведение?

Comment: ты где обработку на клик навешиваешь? что-то мне подсказывает что там собака зарыта

Comment: @Igor пользователь каждый раз кликая отправляет запрос в результате приходит ответ со скриптом, в результате чего выводится консоль. А вот когда кликает по руту, он почему то попадает в `pag/first`, и вот тут скорее всего проблема с роутингом

Comment: @KostiantynOkhotnyk Думаю, при клике на MAIN в `$(".item")` грузится код всей страницы, который навешивает новый обработчик на `$(".nth")`.

Comment: @Igor кстати да, такое поведение очень возможно

Comment: @Igor именно так

Comment: @RezzziCTC Отлично. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятно, при клике по `MAIN` в `$(".item")` грузится код всей страницы, который навешивает новый обработчик на `$(".nth")`.

```
$('.nth').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if ($(this).data("page") == "/") {
    $('.item').empty();
    return;
  }
  ...
```